How to retrieve an object with a foreign key in many-to-many
I have a many-to-many relationship.
class Module(BaseModel):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, null=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(ModuleGroup, db_table='module_group_members')

class ModuleGroup(BaseModel):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, null=False)

I want to retrieve the list of modules and their associated groups, something like this:
{[
  {
  'name' : 'name1'
  'groups' : ['group1', 'group2']
  },
 'name' : 'name2'
  'groups' : ['group6', 'group7']
  }
]}

Tried this:
modules = Module.objects.filter(is_active=True)
print('values_list', list(modules.values('name', 'groups')))

Which gives e:
[{'name': 'name1', 'groups__name': 'group2'}, {'name': 'name1', 'groups__name': 'group2'}, {'name': 'name2', 'groups__name': 'group6'}, {'name': 'name2', 'groups__name': 'group7'}, ]

Is there any way to group the same modules together so that the group names are in a list?

from collections import defaultdict

modules = Module.objects.filter(is_active=True)

# We'll need an intermediary for data transformation
# defaultdict is a good choice because then there's no worry about instantiating new list objects for each new key that is encountered
modules_dict = defaultdict(list)

# Add each group to the list of whatever name it belongs to
for module in modules:
    modules_dict[module['name']].append(module['groups__name'])

# modules_dict will by now look something like:

'''
{
    name1: [group1, group2]
}
'''

# So now it's just a matter of formatting the data structure to your liking
print([{'name': name, 'groups': groups} for name, groups in modules_dict.items()])


first of all
you need to create a models assuming that you have these two models with is_active field into Module class okay
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class ModuleGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, null=False)

class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, null=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(ModuleGroup, db_table='module_group_members')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # Assuming you have this field in your model

then fill some data into your model in my case iam using Django shell
from yourapp.models import Module, ModuleGroup  


# Create some ModuleGroup instances
group1 = ModuleGroup.objects.create(name='group1')
group2 = ModuleGroup.objects.create(name='group2')
group3 = ModuleGroup.objects.create(name='group6')
group4 = ModuleGroup.objects.create(name='group7')

# Create some Module instances and associate them with ModuleGroup instances
module1 = Module.objects.create(name='name1', is_active=True)
module1.groups.add(group1, group2)

module2 = Module.objects.create(name='name2', is_active=True)
module2.groups.add(group3, group4)

after that make this filter
# Fetch the modules and prefetch related groups
modules = Module.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('groups', queryset=ModuleGroup.objects.only('name'))
)

# Prepare the desired output format
result = []
for module in modules:
    groups = [group.name for group in module.groups.all()]
    result.append({
        'name': module.name,
        'groups': groups
    })

if you print list
print(result)

you should get
[{'name': 'name1', 'groups': ['group1', 'group2']}, {'name': 'name2', 'groups': []}]


Thanks, but what is the purpose of the prefetch?  I thought that having the many-to-many would already cause the ModuleGroup information to come in?

Thank you, as per the docs using prefetch_related is an optimization technique that helps reduce the number of database queries and improves performance when accessing related objects in many-to-many or one-to-many relationships It is especially useful when you have a large number of records and want to avoid the N+1 query problem.
Here’s a visual comparison:
• Without prefetch_related: N + 1 queries (1 query for the main objects + 1 query for each related object access)
• With prefetch_related: 2 queries (1 query for the main objects + 1 query for all related objects)

When you access the related objects without using prefetch_related In this case, if you have 10 modules, Django will execute 11 queries: 1 query to fetch the modules and 1 query for each module to fetch its related groups.
And When you use prefetch_related In this case, Django will execute only 2 queries: 1 query to fetch the modules and 1 query to fetch all related groups at once. This significantly reduces the number of queries and improves performance.
Hope this answer your question mr peter
